# How To Read a Square Root from txt file on combobox

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox, vb.net-2010

I'm using VB 2010 and I'm trying to populate a combobox with a name followed by a square root, but all that I was able to obtain is a name followed by an image of a triangle with a question mark at the center. I've tried to change the font but without result.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use      `&radic;`  √ to display the square root character in html

The characters that follow the square root character must have an overline. This is accomplished by creating a span of characters with a CSS style "text-decoration:overline;"

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap; font-size:larger">
&radic;<span style="text-decoration:overline;">&nbsp;X + 1&nbsp;</span>
</span>
```

To display Square symbol:

```
foot<sup>2</sup>
```

shows as foot<sup>2</sup>

Comment: Ok i'll try right now...

i've also a name squared like this foot² .... and i've the same problem, an image of a triangle with a question mark at the center instead of the ² ...